# feature selection and categorical variables encoding

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, categorical-data

In which order should we apply these two steps "categorical variables encoding" and " feature selection" ? Since in case we start with the encoding, if we use one-hot encoding for instance, then we can select some of the categories only.

How can we handle this problem, if it is not related to the order?

I am new to all these methods, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are confused in between feature learning or representation learning and feature selection. Feature learning is a part of feature selection. You can go through the Wiki articles on feature selection and feature learning. The answer to your question is not straight-forward. Depending on your feature selection approach, the order may vary.

Suggested article:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_learning
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection

Comment: which straightforward feature selection method can be used for mixed data (categorical and numerical variables)? I am using GA based feature selection, and google didn't help me about handling mixed data with this method.